# Running testcafe in gitlab CI fails

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, gitlab, testcafe

I am trying to run my end to end tests (using testcafe) during the CI pipeline of gitlab. However, I am running into the following error:

```
ERROR The Firefox 52.0.0 / Linux 0.0.0 browser disconnected. This problem may appear when a browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues.
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml is as follows:

```
stages:
  - test

before_script:
    - apt-get update -yqqq
    - apt-get install -y xvfb
    - apt-get install iceweasel -yqq
    - Xvfb :99 -ac &
    - export DISPLAY=:99

test-frontend:  
  image: node:7.7.4
  stage: test
  script: 
    - npm install
    - npm install -g testcafe@0.19.2
    - testcafe --list-browsers
    - testcafe firefox e2etests/tests/login.test.js
  tags:
    - vue
```

So basically I am using a node docker image for my test 'stage' and install xvfb to 'display' a browser.

**Output ci gitlab:**

```
npm info ok 
$ testcafe --list-browsers
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
firefox
$ testcafe firefox e2etests/tests/login.test.js
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
 Running tests in:
 - Firefox 52.0.0 / Linux 0.0.0

 Try to
ERROR The Firefox 52.0.0 / Linux 0.0.0 browser disconnected. This problem may appear when a browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's very hard to diagnose what causes the problem. This error appears when a browser doesn't respond to the TestCafe server for 2 minutes. In most cases, this means that the browser has crashed or hung completely. Would you please provide us with a link to your web site or emulate this problem with a brand new project?

Comment: In addition, try using latest TestCafe version: 0.21.0.

Comment: @Marion It seems to be a gitlab / Ci issue, when I run the specific test locally it is working

Answer (score 1):

To run Firefox, please also define dbus:

```
  - Xvfb :99 -ac & 
  - export $(dbus-launch)
```

**Update:**

Add the following command before Xvfb:

```
  - apt-get install -y dbus-x11
```

In addition, try the config below. I have checked it on gitlab and it works properly for me:

```
  stages:
    - test

  before_script:
      - apt-get update -yqqq
      - apt-get install -yqq xvfb
      - apt-get install iceweasel -yqq
      - apt-get install dbus-x11 -yqq
      - Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1280x720x24 -ac &
      - export DISPLAY=:99
      - export $(dbus-launch)

  test-frontend:  
    image: node:7.7.4
    stage: test
    script: 
      - npm install
      - npm install -g testcafe
      - testcafe --list-browsers
      - testcafe firefox e2etests/tests/login.test.js
    tags:
      - vue
```

See the full tutorial here: [Integrate TestCafe with GitLab](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/continuous-integration/gitlab.html)

Comment: I am getting: 'dbus-launch: command not found'. However dbus is present

Comment: I have added a complete config to the Answer, which works properly for me.

Comment: Still failing, I was thinking is not the problem that the application is not running (ng server?) So maybe testcafe is trying test but no application is running.

Answer (score 1):

I started with the similar approach couple of days ago. But I quickly realised that `Puppeteer`; `node API` to manage headless-chrome is what I was looking for, the most painless and best possible way to integrate `TestCafe` in `Gitlab CI`.

Lot of resources related to this issue in Google, written by tech-savvy, Kanya West of development world goes above my head (because I am stupid developer who understand only simple code).

Here is how I achieved my goals:

```
npm install testcafe-browser-provider-puppeteer --save-dev

npm install testcafe --save-dev
```

Here is `gitlab-ci`

```
test_e2e_testcafe:
  stage: test
  image: alekzonder/puppeteer
  script:
    - cd app
    - npm install
    - npm start &
    - ./node_modules/.bin/testcafe puppeteer:no_sandbox path-to-test-folder/yourtestfile.js
  except:
    - master
  tags:
    - autoscale
```

Comment: Hi!, thanks for your comment, how did you handle your before script with the pupperteer image? I have some before_script where i set ssh (needed for private repo's)

Comment: @M.Suurland You don't need Xvfb the `testcafe-browser-provider-puppeteer` will take care of that so from your code above before_script can be removed. I don't have a need to set ssh. So  I have no before_script in my case.